# How to manage security in OWB

Tags: oracle, security

I have a problem to manage security in OWB,
First:
It is possible to create another user repository (but not repository owner) that refering to specified repository for example:
I have repository called 'Project' and i have repository owner 'OWB_Owner' so it is possible to create another user that when it login into that 'Project'

Second:
I want the another user just can run the specific mapping in OWB (not all mapping), the repository owner give the priveleges for run mapping for this another user

Hope u can help me solve this problem, thank so much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and that's how it should be done. OWB is a multi-user development environment.

You create your repository with a "repository owner" and add other development users to the repository.

From the "Design Center";
go to "Globals Navigator" --> Security --> Users. You can see the existing users.

To add new users; right-click "Users" and select "New User".

You can add any existing DB users as OWB users or add an entirely new user. In the latter case, new DB user will be created.

To control permission on a mapping;

Select the mapping; 
  Select "View" from the menu.
  Select "Security".